# angular 1.x: shows only first character of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing the problem, where angular (1.5.8) shows only the first character of a string.

```
<h1>User name: {{ user.name }} </h1>
```

renders as `User name: J` where `user.name=Joe'

The controller log output `$log.info(user.name);` gives me `Joe`.

I'm looking for some hint, on how can I find/debug the source of that problem.

Comment: Can you use F12 (developer tools) to check if the full name is in the html? I'm thinking this is a CSS problem.

Comment: please provide [mcve]. this sounds like a very unusual issue

Comment: Have you initialized your object as $scope.user = { name : {} };

Comment: Try putting {{ user.name }} outside the h1. Please, show us the controller code.

Comment: @BobBrinks I know, it's too little info, that I provided. But I don't know, where to start. 
... <h1 class="page-header ng-binding">User name: J</h1> ...